# I want to use google maps with pins on locations and when I click a certain button i want to go to that location. .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I've been searching for this quite a bit and cannot seem to find it anywhere online.

The background story: I am making a .NET windows forms C# application and I have a couple of listbox items that I want to have the following functionality:
When I click on the listbox item I want the map to go to that location with a pin attached to these longitude and latitude coordinates.Also I would like a certain zoom. I would be very thankful is someone could give some information if this is possible.
It would be great if there would exist functions that do this.

Also I want to add a new function to add a new location, that when I add a pin to the map I get the longitude and latitude coordinates back somehow.

I understand events and all that btw, I just don't know how to use any possible functions, that google maps provides for .NET framework.

Comment: go through this document to get the basics of the Google Map, 

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-maps-api-3/drafts/89500

Answer (score 0):

Google maps API is browser API (javascript) as @Mr. J pointed out.

There are third party API's that can be used

https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net

```
        GoogleSigned.AssignAllServices(new GoogleSigned(gmapsApiKey));

        var map = new StaticMapRequest();
        map.Center = new Location("1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043");
        map.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(imgGoogleResult.Width, imgGoogleResult.Height);
        map.Zoom = 14;
        map.Sensor = false;

        Uri imgURI = map.ToUri();
        imgGoogleResult.ImageLocation = imgURI.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: How do I add this to my project, I tried Add refference, but there is no .dll file within these files to include.

Comment: And do I use the functions and documentation  from ?stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-maps-api-3/drafts/895‌​00

Comment: First: havent checked if that API fits your needs, linked it as a sample.
Second: There is a NuGet package named gmaps-api-net. Copy-paste from the project page:

    `PS> Install-Package gmaps-api-net`

Comment: You must choose between the html/javascript solution or the .NET solution. In case of the html/js, yes, follow those instructions, in case o the .NET wrapper, follow this: https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net/wiki (left side links, not much info tho)

Comment: I really am having troubles installing this plugin. I put that folder in my project folder and open my project vb2015 , go to that console and type PS > ..., get an error message:

Comment: PS : Cannot find a process with the name "gmaps-api-net". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS > Install-Package gmaps-api-net
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gmaps-api-net:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Comment: If you can't install it using NuGet console, you can do it also from the "NuGet package manager". In a few minutes I got full sample working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126341/discussion-between-bradbury9-and-roger-federer).